# How to group elements depending on a data property in a v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I would like to group elements depending on "group" property in a v-for loop. This data is fetched from an API.
How could I solve this?

This is what I want:

[image]

This is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/dowhiledo/d7gfr1oy/5/

```js
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    people: [ // ordered by group
      {        name: 'Mary',        group: 1      },
      {        name: 'John',        group: 1      },
      {        name: 'Peter',       group: 1      },
      {        name: 'Freddie',     group: 2      },
      {        name: 'Paul',        group: 2      },
      {        name: 'Alfred',      group: 5      },
      {        name: 'George',      group: 5      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  border: 1px solid blue
}

.group {
  border: 4px solid red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>



<div id="example">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="p in people">
      {{ p.group }} - {{ p.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can create an array (or object) that will hold arrays that represent groups of people. `[[{name: 'Marry'}, {name: 'John'}], [{name:'Freddie'}, ...], ...]` You need to loop through your initial array to group them properly. Then loop through the array/object for each array group, looping through that array group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the perfect use case for a computed property.

Use `Array.reduce` to go over all your array elements and "accumulate" them in a group array.

```
computed: {
groups() {
  return this.people.reduce((groups, item) => {
     const g = item.group
     groups[g] = groups[g] || []
     groups[g].push(item)
     return groups
    }, {})
  }
}
```

Full working example in your updated/forked fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9xfpkL0b/

Answer (score 1):

For you get that result you must **divider** your array by **group**, then you can made a loop in html according theses groups you want.

Try that following code to get your result:

HTML

```
<div id="example">
    <template v-for="group in peopleGroup">
       <ul>
           <li v-for=" people in group">
              {{ people.group }} - {{ people.name }}
           </li>
        </ul>
    </template>
</div>
```

VueJS - Script

```
var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    people: [ // ordered by group
      {        name: 'Mary',        group: 1      },
      {        name: 'John',        group: 1      },
      {        name: 'Peter',       group: 1      },
      {        name: 'Freddie',     group: 2      },
      {        name: 'Paul',        group: 2      },
      {        name: 'Alfred',      group: 5      },
      {        name: 'George',      group: 5      }
    ],
    peopleGroup: {}
  },
  mounted(){
    this.peopleGroup = this.parsePeopleGroup( this.people );
  },
  methods: {
    parsePeopleGroup( arrayPeople ) {
        let newArray = {};
        arrayPeople.map( people => {
        if( !newArray[ people.group ] )
            newArray[people.group] = []

        newArray[people.group].push( people );
      })
      return newArray;
    }
  }
});
```

Here the code: http://jsfiddle.net/qb9dmhy2/20/